Problem with solution using Unity container DI provider as well as Built-in one (SignalR issue)
I am working on a old solution web app where all project where created via NET framework. currently we are upgrading all project to NET core, and right now we are moving ASPNET Web App to APSNET Core web app.
For dependency injection we used Unity Container for resolving, and we are planning to still use that, since removing that would mean that we nee to refactor 98% of code.
Problem I have currently is that I need to upgrade signalr from Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR to Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR (projects need to be for multiple target frameworks so that's why we are upgrading to deprecated Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR).
Old implementations of hubs looked like:
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    public static void SendData(string data)
    {
        GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>().Clients.All.sendData(data);
    }
}

And used GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>() for accessing hub and method inside hub could be static.
This is changed in AspNetCore that HubContext is injected via constructor which is registered inside built-in dependency injection provider. Since we are using UnityContainer, I can not resolve it there, and also I can not register it.
Hubs are now registered inside Program.cs as:
app.MapHub<TestHub>("/testHub");
public class TestHubService : BaseHubService, ITestHub
{
    private readonly IHubContext<TestHub> _hubContext;
    public TestHubService(IHubContext<TestHub> hubContext)
    {
          _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
    public void SendData(string data)
    {
          _hubContext.Clients.All.SendMessage("sendMessage", data);
    }
}

TestHubService is, as well as all other classes in our project, injected via Ioc Unity pattern and is accessed via:
container.RegisterType<ITestHubService, TestHubService>();
...
IocProvider.Resolve<ITestHubService>().SendData(data);

But I get exception that IHubContext<TestHub> does not have default constructor.
I was looking everywhere and couldn't find any similar problem.
I know that issue here is that I am using two DI providers inside same project, but currently that is the only way. Is there any way I could make my app still use Unity DI as default, but if not resolved use Built-in DI provider to resolve IHubContext.
If that is not possible, I will just move signal r to separate API project and make HTTP calls from my current application to make signal R work.
Thanks a lot to everyone.
Tried to use both DI but I constantly get error where class does not have default constructor.

may i know which .net version you are using and which Unity package you are using?

@JalpaPanchal I am migrating from framework 4.8 to core 8.0, creating multitarget project that is using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR for SignalR and Unity 5.11.10

just would like to know is it possible for you to create the separate project fort the signalr?

I have tried to use the Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection package but it only supports in .net core 2 and 3. i have tried some other code with the custom service provider but for the default and Unity DI using both together in one project might not be possible. if you can separate the project that would be great
